# How can I trigger a mouse click followed by keyboard presses with a short-cut key?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, accessibility

I would like to find a script or a short program that when a certain key is pressed, I get left-click on mouse, then right arrow, 10 times in 1 second, for the duration the key is pressed.